# Ultra high pitched noice coming from computer

Tags: desktop-computer, noise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [High-pitched noise coming from computer](https://superuser.com/questions/219518/high-pitched-noise-coming-from-computer)

It happened twice today, first a few minutes after turning on the computer (stopped by itself after a few minutes), then several hours later after I had turned my computer off, it started emitting a faint, ultra high pitched noise.

The noise is not very loud, and almost to high pitch to be audible, but definitely noticeable for my ears.

I sleep in the same room as my computer, so at first I was confused when I had just turned it off and started hearing the noise, so I went out of the room to check if the noise was in my head, but no it was definitely coming from the comp. It stopped when I turned it back on.

What can be the possible causes for this phenomenon?

How can I fix it?

Comment: If it is emitting a sound while turned off it sounds dangerous. There would have to be power bypassing your switch. I vote to close because I don't think this is a real question.

Comment: Is this sound coming from the speakers or from the machine? Did you take the case off and listen for it to narrow it down as it could be anything (or is it from the monitor as I've had monitors make this noise before).