# Whistle (noise) with laptop

Tags: hard-drive, noise

I have a laptop which recently I am hearing an unknown whistle (exhausting noise sound with a high frequency) from it. I found out that the whistle stops in the following situations:

- When I move the scroll of mouse,
- When screen saver is displayed,
- When I take a copy of a file (during copy the whistle stops).

Please take attention that the noisy sound is near hard drive. So, My first idea is that the whistle is related to the hard drive.

The whistle really annoys me!

Any idea about the issue is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [High-pitched noise coming from computer](http://superuser.com/questions/219518/high-pitched-noise-coming-from-computer)

Comment: Who voted to close this question.You describe the symptoms very specifically.   I am not sure that you'll find anybody that knows the answer as it's so unusual.. Maybe also try notebookreviewforum and ask within a section for that particular make/model of laptop

Comment: More likely to be "processor whine".

Comment: @Arjan No it obviously is not a duplicate of that one at the link.  That one you linked to says "The noise doesn't seem to be related to any particular activity, ".  Whereas here he has described very clearly and specifically when it doesn't occur, and there's nothing like that in your link

Comment: The duplicate question itself has links as well, @barlop.

Comment: @Arjan ok. And The OP could provide a link to the noise it makes.  I have had a noise a bit like that on a panasonic toughbook when I minimized windows. The solution for me was to do a system restore to a time before it was doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27019/discussion-between-barlop-and-arjan).

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it seems to come from the hard drive, you could replace the hard-drive with another one to see if it makes a difference.

Another possible source would be the voltage regulators.  I've heard of cases where those can emit noises in the audible range in some circumstances which depend on the computer's power consumption, and hence depend on the activity.

You might like to play with the power-management (e.g. turn off all power-management and force everything to always be set to max-performance) to see if it makes a difference.  Similarly, you can see if the noise disappears if you run a CPU-heavy background task (e.g. take a DVD and convert it to some other format).